# Word count stops functioning when $ character in lstlisting

Tags: listings, word-count

I'm trying to have a lstlisting inside a longlisting, with some bash code. The bash code however ruins the word count function. The listing code is here:

```
\begin{longlisting}
    \centering
    \begin{lstlisting}[language=bash]
sudo apt update && sudo apt install curl gnupg2 lsb-release
sudo curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key  -o /usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg

echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu $(source /etc/os-release && echo $UBUNTU_CODENAME) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list > /dev/null
\end{lstlisting}
\end{longlisting}
```

The word count function is from [this](https://newbedev.com/command-for-character-count-including-spaces-in-overleaf) tutorial

If I run it with backslash before the $, then it works, but not without

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is that TeXcount encounters `$` and interprets it to open a math group which needs another `$` to be ended. This is presumably because TeXcount has not applied any parsing rules to `lstlisting` or `longlisting`.

TeXcount has a rule for the `lstlisting` environment defined as part of the `listings` package, but this is only applied if TeXcount encounters `\usepackage{listings}`.

You can alternatively specify the rule for handling `lstlisting` by including the comment

```
%TC:envir lstlisting [] xall
```

somewhere before first use. This specifies that it takes no required arguments (possibly optional arguments), and the content is completely excluded including symbols such as `$` that normally need to be balanced.

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much